# PyDev Jython - Install and import Python library

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jython, pydev

I'm using Jython to script in runtime in a plugin based on Java in Eclipse. 
When I want to use Python libraries (py_expression_eval, for example) on the scripts, what I'm doing is:

1) install the library using easy_install in Jython standalone (it is installed in: C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval-0.3-py2.7.egg)

2) copy the folder py_expression_eval to C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.jython_4.5.5.201603221110\Lib\site-packages

3) in the script, before importing the library, add this folder above to the classpath using `sys.path.append()`

Is there a way I can install a python library directly to a folder in the classpath, so I could just import the library? What I have in mind is that the Jython standalone has a bin folder with easy_install and pip, but PyDev.Jython does not.